# VoltDB: How to start or compile the database programmatically?

Tags: java, voltdb

I am wondering if VoltDB can be started and controlled using plain java. Since the voltdb is provided as Java implementation it should be possible to control and start / stop a single database / server instance from within a java program.

At least the compiling of a DLL and Procedures inside a jar should be possible to be triggered automatically.

I want to faciliate this in a unit test.

Answer (score 1):

The VoltDB wiki on Github has an article, [Using Eclipse to Develop and Debug VoltDB Client Applications](https://github.com/VoltDB/voltdb/wiki/Using-Eclipse-to-Develop-and-Debug-VoltDB-Client-Applications), that describes how to set up Eclipse to test a java stored procedure.